# Which is the trigger of OOM killer, free or availaible memory in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, performance, out-of-memory

I am working on an embedded Linux system which is on SOC platform.
I have 2 machines ran the same memory workload, and I got following memory output.

Machine 1.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          50616       35304        2516          48       12796       13100
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Machine 2.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          57328       45320        2856          56        9152        9572
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Machine 1 has less `free` memory than machine2, but machine 1 has more `available` memory than machine 2.  In this case, which machine is in higher risk of triggerring OOM killer?
Is there any memory tuning advice?

##### Updated with setting overcommit_memory (sort of off-topic)

Per Fritz answer, in another system, I changed the `overcommit_memory` to 2, no other changes, I got following.

```
# cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio
50
#
# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          84244       25256       35196          92       23792       56772
Swap:             0           0           0
# echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
#
# ls
-/bin/sh: can't fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

The ratio is 50, but it said `cannot allocate memory` when disable memory overcommit.

Even `echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio`, when `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`, it still hit the error, and I had to reboot system.

So per my testing, changing memory overcommit might not get the `pre-defined` Segmentation Fault.

I had accepted Fritz's answer on the kernel memory reclaims on `available` and `free`.

We may open another question to discuss Linux memory overcommit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free` memory is completely unused, while `available` memory can be freed by the kernel immediately if it is needed. It contains things such as file system cache, avoiding reads from the disk and speeding up the system. If you look closely, you can see that the `available` amount is similar to `buff/cache`.

Thus, the kernel *should* not invoke the OOM killer unless the `available` memory is exhausted.

As Andrew pointed out in the comments: The safe option is to [disable overcommitting of memory in the kernel](https://web.archive.org/web/20191217022645/https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html#ss9.6). That way, when a program requests more memory than is currently available, the `malloc` call will return `NULL` instead of succeeding. This means that there can never be more memory allocated than physically available, so the OOM killer will (hopefully) never be invoked:

```bash
# Assuming swap is disabled because it is an embedded system:
echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio  # Commit max 100% of physical RAM (+ Swap, which is off)
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory  # Disable overcommit heuristics
```

However, this requires that (a) your programs do not request much more memory than they intend to use, and (b) that you check the return value of all `malloc` calls and do something *sensible* when they return `NULL`. Otherwise you risk the same behavior as the OOM killer (your process randomly dying), in this case due to a segfault/null dereference.

More tuning advice is difficult without information on the specific scenario you are facing. But if physical memory is exhausted while overcommitted, there is not much that the kernel can do apart from: *swapping*, *killing a process*, or *panicking*. You could try to enable [`zram`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) or  [`zswap`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zswap) (thus "swapping" to RAM) or add a `swapfile`, but both will likely degrade system performance when memory is (nearly) full. Better make sure that your application has no memory leaks.

Comment: I will do a test later to validate which one will trigger the OOM. This is an embedded Linux system, _swap_ is not used for its performance and impacts to storage. And with static analysis and valgrind, I did NOT find memory leakage in the main applications. The memory usage I got above is based on a running system with a stress testing, which also take a little memory.  With `available` value, I think the system is still safe since there is about 20% memory available, there should NOT be OOM killer triggered.

Comment: *But if physical memory is exhausted, there is not much that the kernel can do apart from: swapping, killing a process, or panicking.*  Not lying about available memory in the first place and therefore never having to freak out over the resulting overcommit is the **reliable** option.

Comment: I verifyied Fritz's answer by `malloc/memset` 8MB memory, and the `free`, `buff/cache` and `available` are all descreased. It showed the kernel first reclaim memory from `buff/cache`, then allocated new memory if no more can be reclaimed from `buff/cache`, so the `free` is still NOT exhaused, and there is NO OOM killer triggered to kill the memory hogger. So the conclusion is the system with more `available` memory is less impacted by OOM killer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Sure, disabling overcommit in the kernel, so that malloc returns NULL if all memory is committed, is a viable option (though that is a preventive measure, not something to be done after memory is exhausted as the other options). However, that also requires well-behaved programs that only request as much memory as they actually need. Not sure how much that is true in real life.

Comment: @wangt13: Can you check how disabling overcommit affects the situation?

Comment: My system boots up with 0 of `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`, when I set `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` to 2, then I cannot run any command in the console with the error `/bin/sh: can't fork: Cannot allocate memory`

Comment: @wangt13: Well that's to be expected, because `overcommit_memory=0` tells the system: "You can allocate 0% or RAM + any swap". Since you have no swap, this allows the allocation of exactly 0 bytes of RAM. Try `echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` beforehand, to allow it to use all of the RAM... although I don't know of kernel memory is factored into this limit, or if kernel memory is additional to this limit. Look at the link in the answer for an example program that reports how much memory it can allocate.

Comment: Let me clarify the case. There is a process using lots of memory in system. So far, its memory usage is still less than the `total` memory, it has least risk of using up ALL physical memory. My question was to know in 2 configurations (listed in question), which one might be hit the lower watermark of OOM, I just want to prepare/figure out what is the worst case. I will try `echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` later. I tried to other ways to limit the process's memory usage, which can trigger SEGV from accessing NULL. Now I am tuning the process to use less memory to keep it safe.

Comment: @wangt13 Thanks for clarification, I understand. Tuning the process for low memory usage is the right thing to do. My point (or rather Andrew's point) is: when the kernel is allowed to overcommit memory (the default Linux behavior), then the OOM killer can kick in *without any warning* at any time and your process has *no chance* to react. If you disable overcommitting (by setting `overcommit_memory` to `2`), then your process will instead get a `NULL` from `malloc` (or an exception from C++ `new`), a case to which your process *can* theoretically react, e.g. by freeing some temporary data.

Comment: @wangt13 Sorry, I just spotted an error in my comment. You have to set `overcommit_ratio` to `100`, and NOT `overcommit_memory`. The ratio sets how much memory can be used. On my desktop system, the default value of ratio is `50`. So without swap, Linux would only be allowed to use 50% of my total RAM, which could prevent running any further shell commands. So, set `overcommit_ratio` to `100` first, and *then* set `overcommit_memory` to `2`. Then you should be able to run commands. Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Fritz, I really got your points of playing with memory overcommit ;-), you want to have a predefined behavior not a un-controlled OOM killer. I have not tried tuning memory overcommit when I worked with server platform. I will deep dive in it to check if it can be used in embedded system.

Comment: @Fritz, I updated the question with testing results of memory overcommit, please check it. And I found this question has 2 votes for close, so I think we may open/discuss memory overcommit in another thread.

Comment: @wangt13: You have to set `overcommit_ratio` *before* `overcommit_memory`. In your edit, it looks like you tried to set it afterwards, which would not work due to the "can't fork" error. I wouldn't worry about the close-votes, your question got upvoted and answered. Of course, if you get stuck at another problem, you should answer another question.

Comment: @Fritz: I set `overcommit_ratio` to 100 before I set `overcommit_memory` to 2, otherwise I cannot run any command with error 'can't fork'.